# NoSuchElementException in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am writing a simple program to read from System.in and place the info into an array of LinkedLists. I am having a pretty simple problem but after hours I can't seem to find the problem. Hopefully its nice and obvious. The segment of code throwing the NoSuchElementException is this:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
        int index = scanner.nextInt();
        master[index].addObservation(scanner.next());
}
```

The error is being thrown from the line with the call to the nextInt() method. The problem occurs when I press Cntrl+Z to end input. For some reason, my code is still entering the while loop even though there is not another line of input. The input is in the following form:

```
1 doug
2 edwin
5 casey
4 fred
Cntrl+Z
```

(The pc number followed by the username)

The pc number is being used for the array index and the username is going into the linked list. I have tried placing the EOF char at the end of the last line and as the first char of the last line with no changes. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### FULL CLASS

```
import java.util.*;

public class TermReport 
{

        private static LineUsageData[] master = new LineUsageData[501];
        private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //skip index 0 for index to PC clarity
            for(int i=1; i<501; i++)
            {
                master[i] = new LineUsageData();
            }

            while(scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                int index = scanner.nextInt();
                master[index].addObservation(scanner.next());
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the row...

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
```

...with something like this:

```
while(scanner.hasNextInt())
```

It's another method of the Scanner class.

- **boolean hasNextInt()**
  Returns true if the next token in this
  scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default
  radix using the nextInt() method.

I'm guessing the input you are scanning ends with something other than an int value.

Comment: "I'm guessing the input you are scanning ends with something other than an int value." The question statement already has the input...

Comment: I have added the entire class I am using. And I will try using the hasNextInt method instead.

Comment: Problem solved. I don't understand why .hasNextLine() was returning true when I enter the EOF while .hasNextInt() is not but I will test it further to see why this is the case. Either way thank you @parski!

Comment: @DennisMeng, I'm just saying that if there is a next line the hasNextLine() method will return true and the while loop will be executed. When index is assigned an assumed int value that can or can not exist stuff is bound to go wrong. Using hasNextInt() would be much wiser.

Answer (score -1):

The most likely problem is that you have probably forgotten to initalize the array. You need something along the lines of

```
master = new ObservationList[MAX_INDICIES];
```

in front of the while loop.

It this is not the case, you will need to provide more code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: The OP claims the problem occurs on the line containing 'scanner.nextInt()'. So it's not getting to the line that could have an uninitialised array member.